# Tabulary = bad vertical alignment?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make a table and I am using the tabulary package to have nice column widths. But here the 2nd and 3rd column values are top aligned while I would want them to be vertically centered. How can I do that ?

My current code is :

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{setpagesize=false}{hyperref} 
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.3in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in,includefoot,includehead,headheight=26pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ | L | C | C | }
\hline
\centering A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines \\
\hline 
A random text & 2 & 0.025 \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 2 lines) : $\varepsilon=0.25$ & 2 & ? \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 2 lines) : $\varepsilon=0.5$ & 2 & 1 \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 2 lines) : $\varepsilon=0.75$ & 2 & A \\
\hline
A very very very very very very very very very very very very very long random text : $\varepsilon=0.75$ & 2 & A \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{A random caption.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks !

EDIT : complete code

Comment: please always post a complete document not just a fragment

Comment: sorry, I edited and added everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{setpagesize=false}{hyperref} 
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.3in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in,includefoot,includehead,headheight=26pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\def\zz{\ifx\[$\else\aftergroup\zzz\fi}
\def\zzz{\setbox0\lastbox
\dimen0\dimexpr\extrarowheight + \ht0-\dp0\relax
\setbox0\hbox{\raise-.5\dimen0\box0}%
\ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+\extrarowheight\relax
\dp0=\dimexpr\dp0+\extrarowheight\relax 
\box0
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ | >{\zz}L | >{\zz}C | >{\zz}C | }
\hline
\centering A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines \\
\hline 
A random text & 2 & 0.025 \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 2 lines) : $\varepsilon=0.25$ & 2 & ? \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 2 lines) : $\varepsilon=0.5$ & 2 & 1 \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 2 lines) : $\varepsilon=0.75$ & 2 & A \\
\hline
A very very very very very very very very very very very very very long random text : $\varepsilon=0.75$ & 2 & A \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{A random caption.}
\end{table}
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\def\zz{\ifx\[$\else\aftergroup\zzz\fi}
\def\zzz{\setbox0\lastbox
\dimen0\dimexpr\extrarowheight + \ht0-\dp0\relax
\raise-.5\dimen0\box0 
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ | L | >{\zz}C | >{\zz}C | }
\hline
\centering Long column title .......... & Long column title .......... & Long column title .......... \\
\hline 
A random text & 2 & 0.025 \\
\hline
A random quite long text : $\varepsilon=0.25$ & 2 & ABC \\
\hline
A random quite long text : $\varepsilon=0.5$ & 2 & 123 \\
\hline
A random quite long text : $\varepsilon=0.75$ & 2 & A1B \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I would prefere something more automatic because here you define the spaces manually and it does not work any more if there is a row on 3 lines while others are on 2. I updated the minimal example to show that.

Comment: @user52730 it was more or less vertically centred, taking account of the extra height padding, I'll look at your MWE

Comment: @user52730 I'd missed `zz` from one column which was why it wasn't working, updated with a few other improvements

Comment: Indeed this one seems to work perfectly ! Thank you very much :)
I still have 2 questions : is it possible to do it without changing the row height? And I have a problem to insert a multirow in a cell (it is no more vertically centered ...), do you know how to deal with it ?
Thanks again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I learn about
\usepackage{tabulary}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\def\zz{\ifx\[$\else\aftergroup\zzz\fi}\def\zzz{\setbox0\lastbox\dimen0\dimexpr\extrarowheight + \ht0-\dp0\relax\raise-.5\dimen0\box0} and configure with my self?(Is there any reference)